# Segmentation Fault - malloc 2D array

Tags: c, for-loop, initialization, nested-loops, c89

Trying to create a map for a little game. When initialising the map with 2D arrays using malloc, the main function will run okay when the printMap function is commented out, however when trying to display the map with printMap, it returns a Segmentation fault. Totally lost at why this isn't working. Any help appreciated.

This is work for University, who insist the code is in C89 and I compile with -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror.

GAME.C file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include"random.h"

void createMap(char*** map, int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    int i, j;
    xCoord += 2;
    yCoord += 2;
    char** mapArray;

    mapArray = (char**)malloc(yCoord * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < yCoord; i++) {
        mapArray[i] = (char*)malloc(xCoord * sizeof(char));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < yCoord; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < xCoord; j++) {
            mapArray[i][j] = "0";
        }
    }
    *map = mapArray;
}

void printMap(char** map, int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    xCoord += 2;
    yCoord += 2;
    printf("%d, %d", xCoord, yCoord);
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < yCoord; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < xCoord; i++) {
            printf("%d %d", i, j);
            printf("%c", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

MAIN.C file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include "random.h"
#include "game.h"

int main(void) {
    int xCoord = 5;
    int yCoord = 5;

    char** map;

    createMap(&map, xCoord, yCoord);
    
    printMap(map, xCoord, yCoord);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How did you not get a compiler error here? `mapArray[i][j] = "0";`

Comment: @Lundin it does give a warning, however it does compile. Is this the route of the problem?

Comment: That's not really a 2D array. That's an array of pointers to 1D vectors...

Comment: No it gives you TWO ERRORS when compiling with the options you told us you are using. I'm voting to close this as non-reproducible - either you are compiling some other code than the one you are showing (like not saving the source before compiling) or you are using other compiler options than what you are telling us.

Comment: @Lundin okay so fixing these is the solution? And not something else that's wrong

Comment: There might be other problems as well. Why are you doing these weird `xCoord += 2; yCoord += 2;` lines? You are explicitly asking to access the array out of bounds. Don't do really strange things out of the blue...

Comment: @Lundin for the game, the user enters the playable size for example 5, 5 and the game should print the map with borders, so the += 2 is to increase the arrays to add a border of "*" around the playable area. If that makes sense?

Comment: @tomparko As long as every function has those +=2... anyway, start by compiling the code with the options you say you are using, fix compilation errors and take it from there. You have lots of variable declarations inside functions for example, which wasn't allowed back in 1989.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `createMap` is incorrectly initializing objects of the type `char` with pointers of the type `char *` to which the string literal `"0"` is implicitly converted in these for loops

```
for (i = 0; i < yCoord; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < xCoord; j++) {
        mapArray[i][j] = "0";
    }
}
```

Instead of the string literal you need to use integer character constant `'0'` as for example

```
for (i = 0; i < yCoord; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < xCoord; j++) {
        mapArray[i][j] = '0';
    }
}
```

Another problem is a typo in this loop within the function `printMap`

```
for (j = 0; j < xCoord; i++) {
                        ^^^^
```

You need to write

```
for (j = 0; j < xCoord; j++) {
                        ^^^^
```